# Change build label for Project Cruisecontrol.net

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

After some unexpected changes on the Cruisecontrol.net buildserver the artifacts directories were gone, and the build labels were reset on all projects. How can I change the build label value on the projects? We are using CCNetLabel variable in our scripts.
I tried updating the .state file with no success. it just overwrites the values on the next build. Also tried manipulating the latest log file in the artifact directory

Comment: Can you post your .state file?  I had to do this before and it might trigger my memory if I see your file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `<initialBuildLabel>` value to set it in your .config file.  This [documentation](https://ccnet.github.io/CruiseControl.NET/projects/ccnet/wiki/Default_Labeller.html) for the Default Labeler gives more detail, but here is their example:

```
<labeller type="defaultlabeller">
   <initialBuildLabel>1</initialBuildLabel>
   <prefix>Foo-1-</prefix>
   <incrementOnFailure>true</incrementOnFailure>
   <labelFormat>00000</labelFormat>
</labeller>
```

I *think* this is what I did in my build config when I needed to do this, but have since removed it once it got going at the number I wanted.

Comment: Just a note from someone else who went through a situation similar to Martin's... the docs show that `<initialBuildLabel>` defaults to 1 anyway, so I'm not sure how that helps, though I didn't test it on my end.  Modifying the `.state` file worked fine in my case; I just had to restart the CruiseControl.Net service before running the next build.